# Sort Algorithm in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting

I am going through Programming in Scala where I need some help to understand the sort example provided.  The insertion sort Algorithm looks like this.

```
def isort(xs: List[Int]) : List[Int] = 
 if(xs.isEmpty) Nil
 else insert(xs.head, isort(xs.tail))

def insert(x: Int, xs: List[Int]) : List[Int] = 
 if(xs.isEmpty || x <= xs.head) x:: xs
 else xs.head :: insert(x, xs.tail)
```

To sort the List[Int] = List(4,1,3) the call will go like below.

```
insert(4,isort(1,3))
 insert(1,isort(3))
  insert(2,Nil)
```

Can some one help me from this point how the call to insert function works here.

Comment: If you are not sure _why_ the insertion sort algorithm works, look up a visualization online.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this book is about programming in Scala, examples try to show you the ability of Scala and try to make you familiar with its syntax. I am going to point out three different things according to your question, because I do not know which part of this example made you confused.

**`::` operator**

Quick reminder: Scala's syntax allows you to *use symbols as function name* and you *do not have to use `.`* to reach these functions. Also, if a function takes one parameter, you can *omit `()`*.

`::` operator simply binds to the right. Here is the illustration;

```
scala> 1 :: List(2, 3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> List(2, 3).::(1)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

If you take a look at [this page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html), you'll see common methods and their meanings.

**`head` & `tail` & `last`**

`head` function returns first element of the list, `tail` function returns all elements **except** first one in the list (if list has only one element, it returns empty list `List()`), `last` function returns last element of the list;

```
scala> var x = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
scala> x.head
res2: Int = 1
scala> x.tail
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
scala> x.last
res4: Int = 6
```

**Recursive Function**

Recursive function is just a function which calls itself. For example;

```
def factorial(n: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
     if (n <= 0) acc
     else factorial(n - 1, n * acc)
}
scala> factorial(5, 1)
res5: Int = 120
```

But there is an important point about recursive functions. Our example `factorial` function is tail recursive. From Functional Programming in Scala;

> > A call is said to be 'tail position' if the caller does nothing other than return the value of the recursive call.

When you call `factorial(5, 1)`, here are the sequence of events occurred;

```
factorial(5, 1)
factorial(4, 5)
factorial(3, 20)
factorial(2, 60)
factorial(1, 120)
factorial(0, 120)
120
```

Your example is not tail recursive, because every recursive call has to complete before binding operations. Let's take a look at sequence of events when you call `isort(List(4, 1, 3))`;

```
isort(List(4, 1, 3))
insert(4, isort(List(1, 3)))
insert(4, insert(1, isort(List(3))))
insert(4, insert(1, insert(3, isort(List()))))
insert(4, insert(1, insert(3, Nil)))
insert(4, insert(1, List(3)))
insert(4, List(1, 3))
1 :: insert(4, List(3))
1 :: (3 :: insert(4, List()))
1 :: (3 :: (4 :: List()))
1 :: (3 :: List(4))
1 :: List(3, 4)
List(1, 3, 4)
```

For more information about recursive calls, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37010/5576516).

Comment: "I do not know which part of this example made you confused." – [That's why "Explain this code dump" style questions without a clear explanation of which *precise* parts of the code the OP does and doesn't understand are considered off-topic.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988)

Answer (score 1):

`insert(3, Nil)`
Will evaluate to `List(3)` as it will fall into the first if, and will be equal to `3 :: Nil`.

`insert(1, isort(3))` = `insert(1, insert(3, Nil))` = `insert(1, List(3))`
Will evaluate to `List(1,3)`, as it will also fall into the first if, because 1 is less than the head of `List(3)`.

`insert(4, isort(1,3))` = `insert(4, insert(1, isort(3)))` = `insert(4, List(1,3))`
Will fall in the second if inside the insert function, and will return `1 :: insert(4, 3)`. The `insert(4,3)` will also fall into the second if, and will return `3 :: insert(4, Nil)`. The `insert(4, Nil)` will evaluate to `List(4)`. So in the end `insert(4, List(1,3))` will return `1 :: 3 :: 4`.

Answer (score 0):

As written, `insert` code is recursive. It means, if `x` is less than `head` of the passed array, which is a sorted array (`insert(xs.head, isort(xs.tail))`) , so `x` inserted as a first element of the array using concatenation mark (`:`).

Else, the `insert` function called recursively on the passed array without its head, up to insert `x` into the proper location in the passed array.